# Crystal Reports 2011 - Integer to String and back to Integer

Tags: string, crystal-reports, integer

I have a SQL column that is calculating a date diff which is obviously an integer. What I need to happen is, in my mind, quite simple; yet I cannot find the syntax to make it work.

The goal is to take all NULL values and make them say "Missing" while keeping the rest of the data in the column an integer.

I did this to make NULLS = 0 (tonumber() is not really needed, I just haven't changed it yet):

`if isnull({Command.DAYS_OUT}) = true then 0 else tonumber({Command.DAYS_OUT})`

But what I really want it to say is `if isnull({Command.DAYS_OUT}) = true then "Missing" else {Command.DAYS_OUT}`. Unfortunately, Crystal spits out that stupid "A string is required here". Well, I DONT WANT A STRING!

I cannot use totext() on the ELSE statement. I need to use Highlight Expert to say, if missing then red, if < 0 then red/bold, and between 1 & 30 yellow/bold. When I use totext(), it cant figure out what a number is... :(

Please help...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a single formula that outputs multiple data types. Instead, you can have your formula output a string like you already mentioned:

`if isnull({Command.DAYS_OUT}) then "Missing" else totext({Command.DAYS_OUT})`

Then, to get your font color formatting the way you want, you can use the original integer value:

```
if isnull({Command.DAYS_OUT}) or {Command.DAYS_OUT} < 0 then crRed
else if {Command.DAYS_OUT} in 1 to 30 then crYellow
else crBlack
```

And then do the same for the font type:

```
if isnull({Command.DAYS_OUT}) then crRegular
else if {Command.DAYS_OUT} < 0 or {Command.DAYS_OUT} in 1 to 30 then crBold
else crRegular
```